# Bulk insert records if don't exist in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails application with `Student`, `Group`, and `StudentGroup` models. Groups have many students through `StudentGroup`. I need to be able to bulk add students to a group in an efficient manor. My current (slow) code is as such

```
  def add_students
    if params[:student_emplids].presence
      Student.find(params[:student_emplids]).each do |student|
        @group.student_groups.where(student: student).first_or_create
      end
    end

    respond_with @group
  end
```

How would I improve this code?

Comment: how does `Student.find(params[:student_emplids])` return more than one student??

Comment: @bjhaid If `params[:student_emplids]` is an array, it will use an `IN ()` query.

Comment: It'd be better to use `where` if that's the case to make it clear what to expect. `find` is a little too clever for its own good.

Answer (score 1):

Add the [active_record_bulk_insert](https://github.com/bjhaid/active_record_bulk_insert) gem to your `Gemfile` and bundle

```
#Get the ids of the students
student_ids = Student.where(id: *params[:student_emplids]).pluck(:id)

#Get `students` with `student_groups`
student_with_group_ids = StudentGroup.where(student_id: *params[:student_emplids]).pluck(:student_id)

#create a list of student_groups and bulk_insert them
StudentGroup.bulk_insert((student_ids - student_with_group_ids).map { |id| {:student_id => id, :group_id => @group.id} })
```